# When I enter a number between 0 to 70 it prints infinitely

Tags: c++, while-loop

When I enter a value between 0 to 70 it prints infinitely (which is wrong), but when input a number that is not between 0 to 70 it prompts the user to enter a number that should be between 0 to 70. (which is correct)

```
        while (true)
        {
            if (hourswork < 0 || hourswork > 70)
            {
                cout<<"Please enter a value between 0 to 70: ";
                cin>>hourswork;
            }
            else
            {
                wages = RATE * hourswork;
                cout << "The wage is: " << wages << endl;   
            }
        }
```

The result when I enter a value between 0 to 70 should only be printed once.

Comment: When and where do you break out of the loop? When will the condition `true` ever become false? Some quick [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) should have given you the answer quicker and easier than writing up this question.

Comment: you should break the loop when you condition is matched and you have to put && instead of ||

Comment: when I enter a value between 0 to 70 (e.g. 1), it prints out 1 endlessly. I dont know how to prevent that from happening.

Comment: @Amy when I put && it also prints endlessly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should reconsider what you have in your `while` loop. Do you really want the output in there? You probably only want the loop to get input until it's valid. The output should instead be moved out of the loop:

```
int main() {
    int hourswork = -1;
    int RATE = 123;
    while (hourswork < 0 || hourswork > 70)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a value between 0 to 70: ";
        cin >> hourswork;
    }

    int wages = RATE * hourswork;
    cout << "The wage is: " << wages << endl;
}
```

This way it will ask for a `hourswork` value until it is valid, which then stops the loop, and unconditionally does the print part once after the loop.

---

Generally the reason why your loop never terminated is because `while (true)` won't stop looping unless you get out of it with a `break`, `return` or something similar, neither of which is present in your code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to leave your loop with a `break` when your `hourswork` was within range.

Like this:

```
while (true)
{
    if (hourswork < 0 || hourswork > 70)
    {
        cout<<"Please enter a value between 0 to 70: ";
        cin>>hourswork;
    }
    else
    {
        wages = RATE * hourswork;
        cout << "The wage is: " << wages << endl;   
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer is right but you should avoid should avoid conditions in loop as much as you can, it effects on performance of application, @Blaze answer is perfect as per performance